# A better way to handle the below Sql query filtering condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Consider the below SQL query

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[PartnerCommissionData] 
SELECT X.*
FROM
(
        SELECT 
                cs.partner_id
                ,cs.quarter 
                ,cs.year
                ,cs.partner_currency_amount
                ,p.partner_email                        
                ,cs.report_status_id    
                ,Creation_dt = GETDATE()    
        FROM [dbo].[CommissionSummary] cs WITH(NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Partner] p WITH(NOLOCK) ON p.partner_id = cs.partner_id
        WHERE  
                cs.year = YEAR(@FirstDayOfQuarter)  
        AND     cs.quarter = @Quarter
        AND     cs.report_status_id IN (1,2)
    )X
WHERE 
    X.partner_id NOT IN (SELECT [Partner_Id] FROM [dbo].[PartnerCommissionData] WITH (NOLOCK))
AND X.quarter NOT IN (SELECT [Quarter] FROM [dbo].[PartnerCommissionData] WITH (NOLOCK))
AND X.year NOT IN (SELECT [Year] FROM [dbo].[PartnerCommissionData] WITH (NOLOCK))
AND X.report_status_id NOT IN (SELECT [CommissionStatus_id] FROM [dbo].[PartnerCommissionData] WITH (NOLOCK))
```

The filtering condition specified indicates that if the record already present in the PartnerCommissionData table, then it should not be inserted further. But as per me it's a kind of nasty implementation.

```
WHERE 
    X.partner_id NOT IN (SELECT [Partner_Id] FROM [dbo].[PartnerCommissionData] WITH (NOLOCK))
AND X.quarter NOT IN (SELECT [Quarter] FROM [dbo].[PartnerCommissionData] WITH (NOLOCK))
AND X.year NOT IN (SELECT [Year] FROM [dbo].[PartnerCommissionData] WITH (NOLOCK))
AND X.report_status_id NOT IN (SELECT [CommissionStatus_id] FROM [dbo].[PartnerCommissionData] WITH (NOLOCK))
```

How can we rewrite it in a better fashion?

Can we apply a merge or any other way....?

Thanks in advance

Comment: But you have `NOLOCK`, isn't that the magic turbo button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do something like this ? Don't need to left join (scanning another table). 
assume partner_id, quarter , year , report_status_id need to convert to nvarchar

```
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[PartnerCommissionData] 
    SELECT X.*
    FROM
    (
            SELECT 
                    cs.partner_id
                    ,cs.quarter 
                    ,cs.year
                    ,cs.partner_currency_amount
                    ,p.partner_email                        
                    ,cs.report_status_id    
                    ,Creation_dt = GETDATE()    
            FROM [dbo].[CommissionSummary] cs WITH(NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Partner] p WITH(NOLOCK) ON p.partner_id = cs.partner_id
            WHERE  
                    cs.year = YEAR(@FirstDayOfQuarter)  
            AND     cs.quarter = @Quarter
            AND     cs.report_status_id IN (1,2)
       )X
    WHERE 
    (x.partner_id + x.quarter + x.year + x.report_status_id) <> 
    (partner_id + x.quarter + x.year + x.report_status_id)
```

Comment: I wouldn't put too much faith into `CHECKSUM`. There are many documented cases where it can produce identical values for very similar (but not identical) rows...

Comment: can you cast them to `char` for values compare?

Answer (score 0):

Perform joins rather than inner selects. This is very messy SQL. Think in sets rather than procedures.

Answer (score 0):

So if my understanding is correct, you are avoiding inserting data that might have duplicates, I changed your SQL to something as follow:

```
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[PartnerCommissionData] 
SELECT X.*
FROM
(
        SELECT 
                cs.partner_id
                ,cs.quarter 
                ,cs.year
                ,cs.partner_currency_amount
                ,p.partner_email                        
                ,cs.report_status_id    
                ,Creation_dt = GETDATE()    
        FROM [dbo].[CommissionSummary] cs WITH(NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Partner] p WITH(NOLOCK) ON p.partner_id = cs.partner_id
        WHERE  
                cs.year = YEAR(@FirstDayOfQuarter)  
        AND     cs.quarter = @Quarter
        AND     cs.report_status_id IN (1,2)
    )X
    LEFT JOIN [PartnerCommissionData] PCD WITH (NOLOCK)) 
            ON X.partner_id = PCD.[Partner_Id] OR X.quarter = PCD.[Quarter] 
                OR X.year = PCD.[Year] OR X.report_status_id = PCD.[CommissionStatus_id]
WHERE PCD.ID IS NULL
```

The thing I'm trying to do here is first LEFT JOIN the table and try to grab any data if they exist, and then using the IS NULL check to filter out any existing data, so that we do not need the NOT IN which doesn't perform well and not recommended.

Comment: what is PCD.ID..should it be PCD.[Partner_Id]?

Comment: It should be the PK on the table, sorry I don't know if Partner_Id is the one so I put ID there, it should be a column that never contain NULL in it